# What test should i use to prove A is better than B

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, descriptive-statistics

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/llaG1.jpg]

I have sets of data that have number of goods produced by 2 machines, A & B for 2 months. Each machines has two numbers that is plan value and actual value. I'm not really familiar with hypothesis testing or other statistical method, can somebody help me what test that is suitable to prove one machine is better than another or vice versa.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What would “better” mean to you? Does it just mean that the “actual” results are higher (or lower), or does it involve the planned values?

Comment: better in terms that actual result are higher

Comment: Better in terms of mean or something else? Does the fact that machine B have a low outlier matter to you?

You should probably take a course or two in statistics.

Answer (score 2):

**Data and description.** Suppose 'actual' values for Machines A and B are as shown below (very similar
to the observations in your question, but not *exactly* the same.)

```
a = c(141,930,293,381,414,848,615,129,550)
b = c(259,922,962,861, 61,343,710,738,690)
```

Summary statistics from R statistical software are as follows:

```
summary(a); sd(a)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  129.0   293.0   414.0   477.9   615.0   930.0 
[1] 284.6614     # SD
summary(b); sd(b)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   61.0   343.0   710.0   616.2   861.0   962.0 
[1] 318.7035     # SD
```

Sample sizes are small (too small for formal tests of normality to be useful).
Boxplots show no outliers, but do show that all values for A are included between the minimum and maximum of B.

```
boxplot(a,b, col="skyblue2", pch=19, names=c("A","B"))
```

[image]

**Welch 2-sample t test.** It seems reasonable to do a Welch 2-sample t test of $H_0: \mu_A = \mu_B$ against the alternative
$H_a: \mu_A \ne \mu_B.$ [But we have no reason to believe that population variances for A and B are the same, so it's not good practice to use
a pooled t test.]

A Welch 2-sample t test returns P-value about $0.35 > 0.05,$ so we cannot
reject the null hypothesis at the 5% level. Output from R:

```
t.test(a,b)

        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  a and b
t = -0.97116, df = 15.8, p-value = 0.3461
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -440.6048  163.9382
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 477.8889  616.2222
```

Because the sample mean for A (about 472) is smaller than the sample
mean for B (about 616), you might guess (or hope) that machine A tends to give
smaller values than machine B, but relative to the variability in the
values from the two machines, the difference is not statistically meaningful.
Differences of this size would likely occur *by chance alone* about a third
of the time, if similar data were collected in the future.

*Notes:*

(1) You said in a Comment on @Dave's Answer (+1) that the data you posted are
only part of the data you have. The conclusions here are for data essentially the same as the data you posted. If you have a *lot more* data, it is possible
that you may find a significant difference. [In view of the variability in the data your show: in order to have an 80%, 90%, or 95% chance of detecting a difference of 170 in 'actual' means (5% level), you would need about 50, 70, 80, respectively, observations from each machine.]

(2) Output from Minitab statistical software for the same data is shown below.
Minitab has slightly different conventions for rounding output, but the results are in substantial agreement with the results above from R.

```
Two-Sample T-Test and CI 

Sample  N  Mean  StDev  SE Mean
1       9   477    285       95
2       9   616    319      106

Difference = μ (1) - μ (2)
Estimate for difference:  -139
95% CI for difference:  (-443, 164)
T-Test of difference = 0 (vs ≠): 
T-Value = -0.98  P-Value = 0.344  DF = 15
```

(3) You have not explained the meaning or relevance of the numbers listed as `Plan`, so I have not included them in my analysis above. It may be 
that you need to do a two sample t test of the difference `Actual - Plan`
for machine A compared to the same kind of difference for machine B.

Comment: Adding to point #3, that is different from a paired t-test!

Comment: Then let $U = $ A actual - A plan, so that $U_1 = 141 - 97,$ etc. (Make sure that is a meaningful measure of something having to do with machine performance.) Similarly for $V$ and machine B. Then its a paired test for $U_i$s vs. $V_i.$s. This sort of thing is sometimes called 'difference of differences'.

Answer (score 1):

The classic way to do this, the way your boss wants you to do it, is called the two-sample t-test. There are countless resources for reading how the test works. You will find software implementations in whatever you want. R does it as t.test(a,b,alternative=“greater”). If you’re comfortable in Excel, you can do it there, too.

There are some issues with your sample size. I ran a t-test on your values, and there is no significant difference between the groups.

Additionally, it appears that B is greater than A.

**Edit**

As a heads up, the default in R is to use the Welch test. Other software may assume equal variances. Know what test your software does when you tell your boss what you did.

Comment: thanks dave for the suggestions, well actually that is not the full data. anyway, appreciate for your help!

Comment: @qiopy There’s a lot that you can do if you have a larger data set. How many observations do you have from each machine? Also, I want to understand the question better: if all that interests you is the actual result, why track the plan”? Perhaps you really don’t care about the plan, but a) you’re allowed to, and b) there are ways of handling outperform and underperforming the planned result. Maybe you really don’t care about the planned result, but including it makes me curious.